# Truecrypted Windows 7 missing in Grub2 after upgrade

Tags: grub2, windows, truecrypt

I have an encrypted dual boot Windows 7/Ubuntu System and upgraded my Ubuntu today.

Everything went smooth but my Windows is not shown in the Grub2-List anymore.
Starting up I have the Truecrypt Bootloader and after entering the Password I get to Grub (now Grub2). There my Windows 7 entry is missing now.

Here is my report:
http://paste.ubuntu.com/7569182/

Updating Grub did nothing to it. My guess is that within Ubuntu it does not recognize my Windows Installation on sda1 anymore. I can't mount it aswell.

I can only mount it via Truecrypt itself. I think I might have to manually insert the menu item for Windows into that Grub config file. I guess that after entering the password in the truecrypt bootloader it would be possible to start Windows if the item was there - just a guess though.

Edit:
I basically followed these steps to set up my system:
[Dual Booting Windows 7 with Ubuntu 12.04LTS with Truecrypt](http://utcomsoc.ece.utexas.edu/index.php/knowledge-base/28-it-tips-and-tricks/51-dual-booting-windows-7-with-ubuntu-12-04lts-with-truecrypt)

Comment: Can I somewhere find my old grub config file, downgrade grub or such? - Maybe someone with a similar system could just post his menu entry in that config file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the solution was rather simple and my initial guess was right.
I just added the following via
`sudo gedit /etc/grub.d/40_custom`

```
menuentry "Windows 7" {
set root=(hd0,msdos1)
chainloader +1
}
```

where `hd0` represents my disk and `msdos1` my Windows OS on the first partition of my SSD `sda1`. To find out which partition number you need you can use

```
sudo fdisk -l
```

which gave me

```
   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1            2048   134219775    67108864    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda2       201328640   250066943    24369152    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda3   *   134219776   134610943      195584   83  Linux
/dev/sda4       134610944   201328639    33358848   83  Linux
```

I then ran the following to update my `/boot/grub/grub.cfg`

```
sudo update-grub2
```

To verify the entry is in your config file just check by

```
cat /boot/grub/grub.cfg
```

Done.

The Problem I think is, that only at the time of bootloading into Grub2, TrueCrypt decrypted the Windows Partition to enable booting from it. Don't forget in my setup the first thing showing up is the TrueCrypt bootloader chaining into Grub2. Running ubuntu though, the partition is encrypted again and `sudo update-grub2` just finds raw binary data.

For related problems I suggest to just try different entries in your 40_custom file before you do major changes to your system itself! Thus will be much safer - I did not have to do an image of my disc and did not have to fear data loss. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that Ubuntu has no idea what are those partition about:

```
sda1: ____________________________________________________

    File system:       
    Boot sector type:  Unknown
    Boot sector info: 
    Mounting failed:   mount: unknown filesystem type ''

sda2: ____________________________________________________

    File system:       
    Boot sector type:  Unknown
    Boot sector info: 
    Mounting failed:   mount: unknown filesystem type ''
mount: unknown filesystem type ''
```

So, you need to tell Ubuntu how to read it. For this you should try mounting the encrypted filesystem and save your data first. Download the Linux version of Truecrypt from a secure source (**truecrypt.sourceforge.com is not secure anymore**). This step is done as precaution. Do the same with the contents of the `/boot` directory.

Now, verify you have installed in the live installation the cryptsetup package. It should be able to detect truecrypt filesystems without problems. Now, use grub-install to fix your boot:

```
sudo mkdir /mnt/{boot,ntfs1,ntfs2}
sudo cryptsetup --type tcrypt open /dev/sda1 /mnt/ntfs1
sudo cryptsetup --type tcrypt open /dev/sda2 /mnt/ntfs2
sudo mount /dev/sda3 /mnt/boot
sudo grub-install --boot-director=/mnt/boot /dev/sda
```

Then, I expect that before doing this you have, a full image of the disk, back up of your important information, etc. since I cannot guarantee it would work (ie, grub blowing up the truecrypt bootloader).

Comment: Thanks so far, I'll try that. (Also thanks for the edit :)) I added some additional information to the question.